# Finding Explicit Solution Of An Implicit Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx} + 1 = 2y$, $y(1) = 1$

**My Work So Far**

Equation can be rearranged as:

$dy = (2y-1)dx \to$

$ \int dy = \int(2y-1)dx \to$

$ y = 2xy-x + C \to$

$y-2xy = C-x\to$

$y = \frac{C-x}{1-2x}$

For $y(1) = 1$:

$1 = \frac{C-1}{1-2(1)} \to$

$1 = \frac{C-1}{-1} \to$

$C = 1-1 \to C = 0$

Therefore, $y = \frac{-x}{1-2x}$

However, this is apparently wrong; the answer given is:

$y = \frac{1}{2}(1+e^{2x-2})$

Which is totally baffling to me; I've run through my solution over and over and can't find what I'm doing wrong, or what scenario would possibly lead to having to incorporate natural logs. Would anyone be able to point out where I'm going wrong in my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You integrated $x$ with respect to $y$, which you can't do in this situation. The correct procedure is as follows:

$dy = (2y-1)dx$

$\int \frac{1}{2y-1}dy = \int 1dx$

$\frac{1}{2}ln|2y-1| = x + c$

$ln|2y-1| = 2x + 2c$

$2y - 1 = Ae^{2x}, A = e^{2c}$

$y = \frac{Ae^{2x}+1}{2}$

Can you proceed from here?

In case you get stuck:

$y(1) = 1 \Rightarrow 1 = \frac{Ae^{2}+1}{2}$

$A = e^{-2}$

Then we get $y = \frac{1}{2}(e^{2x-2}+1)$ as required

Comment: Your answer makes sense now that I know my integration was incorrect. Why is that the case, though? Why can I not perform $\int (2y-1)dx$ in this case?

Comment: It's to do with the definition of integration. Since $y$ is an dependent variable, we cannot integrate it with respect to $x$ in this fashion. However there are cases when you can, such as when considering partial derivatives (in this case you would treat $y$ as a constant when integrating).

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll accept your answer when the clock runs out.

Comment: @mrnovice The problem is actually that $y$ is a *dependent* variable, i.e. it depends on the variable of integration $x$.

Comment: @Ian Yes mistake by me, corrected now

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $\int y dx = xy$ when $y$ is a function of $x$. In particular, you did not separate the variables since your right side involves both $x$ and $y$. If you want to separate variables, that works, and you can write the equation as $\frac{dy}{2y-1}=dx$. You can instead treat it as first order linear and approach it by the method of integrating factors, in which case you could replace that $1$ with a function of $x$ if you wanted.